# How to clear all inputs, selects and also hidden fields in a form using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to clear all inputs,
selects and also all hidden fields in a form.
Using jQuery is an option if best suited.

What is the easiest way to do this... I mean easy to understand and maintain.

**[EDIT]**

The solution must not mess with check-boxes (the value must remain, but checked state must be cleared), nor the submit button.

What I am trying to do is a clear button, that clears all the options entered by the user explicitly, plus hidden-fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use the [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) method:

```
$('#myform')[0].reset();
```

or without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('myform').reset();
```

where `myform` is the id of the form containing the elements you want to be cleared.

You could also use the [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector if the fields are not inside a form:

```
$(':input').val('');
```

Comment: `reset()` will not do it... if the form already comes with values. Also, clearing all inputs has the side effect of clearing my input buttons and also the submit button... also it does clear value of check-boxes wich is not the behaviour I am looking for.

Comment: @Miguel Angelo, then try excluding them from your selector: `$(':input').not(':checkbox, :submit').val('');`

Answer (score 23):

To clear all inputs, including hidden fields, using JQuery:

```
// Behold the power of JQuery.
$('input').val('');
```

Selects are harder, because they have a fixed list. Do you want to clear that list, or just the selection.

Could be something like

```
$('option').attr('selected', false);
```

Comment: I want to clear just the selection, so that the user must choose it again. It is basically a *clear form button*, but I need it to clear all user choices.

Comment: If I set the val for a check-box, then I am in trouble. I have to change the checked state to not checked... it seems there is no single-line-of-code that will do it all.

Comment: Also, this clears the contents of my submit buttons, and other buttons.

Comment: You're right. The `'input'` selector selects all elements. You could add a few nuances by using `'input[type="text"]` to get text elements only. In the same way you can select checkboxes too, and use `attr` to clear the `checked` property, just as `selected` is cleared on the options. But apparently, there's also the `reset` method on the form element itself. I wasn't aware of that. It will take only a couple of lines to clear every element in my way, but resetting the form is neater anyhow.

Comment: I'll leave this answer for demonstration, but my votes go to roXon for being the first, and to Darin for giving a no-JQuery solution.

Comment: This option is useful, but does cause a "The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present." error in mvc.net, because this token is in a hidden input

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#formID')[0].reset(); // Reset all form fields
```

Comment: this gets me: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined

Comment: @CaseyCrookston `$('#formID')[0]` - that `[0]` takes the JS Element reference out of the jQuery object - so it implicitly searches your page for that element. While `$('#formID')` will not throw any error (if the element is not found) - on the other side operating over a JS element object will throw that error. Cure? Simply make sure that your element exists on your page `if($('#formID')[0]){ /*form exists*/ }`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply clear value to a specific number of fields, then assign id or class to them and apply empty value to them. like this:

```
$('.all_fields').val('');
```

where `all_fields` is class applied to desired input fields for applying empty values.
It will protect other fields to be empty, that you don't want to change.

Answer (score 2):

I had a slightly more specialised case, a search form which had an input which had autocomplete for a person name. The Javascript code set a hidden input which `from.reset()` does not clear.

However I didn't want to reset all hidden inputs. There I added a class, `search-value`, to the hidden inputs which where to be cleared.

```
$('form#search-form').reset();
$('form#search-form input[type=hidden].search-value').val('');
```

Comment: Best answer. Takes care of hidden and everything else.

Comment: You meant `$('form#search-form')[0].reset();` right?

Answer (score 0):

for empty all input tags such as input,select,textatea etc. run this code

```
$('#message').val('').change();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this inside your jquery code or it can stand alone:

```
window.onload = prep;

function prep(){
document.getElementById('somediv').onclick = function(){
document.getElementById('inputField').value ='';
  }
}
```

Comment: This would clear only one input, would you query every single input in your form by id if there were more of them in form?

Comment: Clears only the input field you give by id. This solution helps when you want to determinate which field want to clear and which field you want to keep. I prefer this way (control which fields to clear) then reset();. I have bad experiences with reset(), sometimes it let some data in the field...

Comment: OP wrote *I would like to clear **all** inputs, selects and also **all** hidden fields in a form* so he doesn't want to keep any field filled.